# ExtJS--updating DIV in parent container shifts content in child containers down

Tags: html

I have a panel with a cards layout with multiple cards. I added a div tag to the panel as a central notification area to show alerts/notifications for all cards. This way, I dont need to add a div tag to each card. But when the notification shows up in the top right of the screen, it shifts all the contents of the card down, and when notification disappears the contents move back up.

```
 My.cards.Panel
   ,extend:"Ext.panel.Panel"
   ,border: false
   ,bodyStyle:"padding:5px;"
   ,layout:{type:"card", deferredRender:true}

   ,html:[<div id = centralnotificationbar align = right>,</div>]
   ,initComponent: function() {
      // all cards are in here in separate containers
    }
```

and then to update DIV i do

```
Ext.get("centralnotificationbar).update("<img src='image.png' style='width:16px;height:16px;'> <span style='color:#00FF00;'>"+messageGoesHere+"</span>");
```

I also use Ext.Function.defer to make the notification disappear after x milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div is a [`block element`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) which means that it affects the blocks under it such as the cards. You need to change its CSS so that it becomes `inline`. There are multiple ways to do that, you can declare the `display` property to be `inline`, or you could make a `float:right`, etc.